# Super simple example for a Delegate-Event in c#.net?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-3.0

I need a very simple example to understand myself about the events.I am feeling very difficult to understand the examples available in internet or books.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a simple implementation of a class that exposes an event.

```
public class ChangeNotifier
{
    // Local data
    private int num; 

    // Ctor to assign data
    public ChangeNotifier(int number) { this.num = number; } 

     // The event that can be subscribed to
    public event EventHandler NumberChanged;

    public int Number
    {
        get { return this.num; }
        set
        {
            // If the value has changed...
            if (this.num != value) 
            {
                // Assign the new value to private storage
                this.num = value;

                // And raise the event
                if (this.NumberChanged != null)
                    this.NumberChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This class may be used something like as follows:

```
public void SomeMethod()
{
    ChangeNotifier notifier = new ChangeNotifier(10);

    // Subscribe to the event and output the number when it fires.
    notifier.NumberChanged += (s, e) => Console.Writeline(notifier.Number.ToString());

    notifier.Number = 10; // Does nothing, this is the same value
    notifier.Number = 20; // Outputs "20" because the event is raised and the lambda runs.
}
```

Regarding control flow, execution flows into `SomeMethod()`.  We create a new `ChangeNotifier` and thus call its constructor.  This assigns the value of `10` to the private `num` member.

We then subscribe to the event using the `+=` syntax.  This operator takes a delegate on the right hand side (in our case, that delegate is a lambda) and adds it to the collection of delegates on the event.  This operation doesn't execute any code that we've written in the `ChangeNotifier`.  It can be customized through the `add` and `remove` methods on the event if you'd like, but there's rarely a need to do that.

Then we perform a couple simple operations on the `Number` property.  First we assign `10`, which runs the `set` method on the `Number` property with `value = 10`.  But the `num` member is already valued at `10`, so the initial conditional evaluates to false and nothing happens.

Then we do the same thing with `20`.  This time the value is different, so we assign the new value to `num` and fire the event.  First we verify that the event is not null.  It's null if nothing has subscribed to it.  If it's not null (ie, if something *is* subscribed to it), we fire it using the standard method/delegate syntax.  we simply call the event with the event's arguments.  This will call all methods that have subscribed to the event, including our lambda that will perform a `Console.WriteLine()`.

---

Henrik has successfully nitpicked the potential race condition that exists if one thread can be in `Number`'s setter while another thread is unsubscribing a listener.  I don't consider that a common case for someone who doesn't yet understand how events work, but if you're concerned about that possibility, modify these lines:

```
if (this.NumberChanged != null)
    this.NumberChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
```

to be something like this:

```
var tmp = this.NumberChanged;
if (tmp != null)
    tmp(this, EventArgs.Empty);
```

Comment: Race condition on the != null --line, as NumberChanged can be unsubscribed by another thread if you had more of them.

Comment: +1 for all the info. Sorry I am new to software development, but how are the edited 3 lines different from the above 2 lines of code, what will "this" in the later 3 lines of code refer to and how will it solve thread problem? please could you elaborate on this ? Thanks!

Comment: Suppose the initial condition has a single delegate subscribed to this.NumberChanged.  Thread A tests and finds the event is not null, then thread B unsubscribes the delegate.  Then Thread A tries to execute the (now null) event.  Crash.  If Thread A grabs the delegate list into tmp first, the program will no longer crash.  This does mean that it's possible for an delegate to be run after it's been unsubscribed from the event, so event handler delegates must be robust against this situation.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Parent p = new Parent();
        }
    }

    ////////////////////////////////////////////

    public delegate void DelegateName(string data);

    class Child
    {
        public event DelegateName delegateName;

        public void call()
        {
            delegateName("Narottam");
        }
    }

    ///////////////////////////////////////////

    class Parent
    {
        public Parent()
        {
            Child c = new Child();
            c.delegateName += new DelegateName(print);
            //or like this
            //c.delegateName += print;
            c.call();
        }

        public void print(string name)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("yes we got the name : " + name);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Class A {
    public delegate void EventHandler();

    public static event EventHandler workComplete();

    void doWork(){
        // DO WORK  
    }

    void onWorkComplete(){
        // Raise event
        workComplete();
    }
}

Class Main {
    A a = new A();
    a.workComplete += new () -> {
        // On Class Complete Work
        Console.WriteLine("Work Complete");
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have C background, you can see delegate as a pointer to function.

Comment: Delegate won't be a problem.But understanding events is the real problem for me.

Comment: The question is about events.