# Can lambdas be used without Linq?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I'd rather not use Linq if I don't have to (I remove references to it when I start a new project).  Lambdas look useful, though.  I'm not going to get in the habit of using lambdas, however, if Linq has to tag along for the ride.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you want to use Linq? You might as well try to avoid in heritance, or function calls. It's a part of the language for a reason, and it lets you write cleaner, simpler, better code.

Comment: Keep in mind that LINQ refers to a variety of things: LINQ-to-SQL is different from LINQ-to-XML, and when combined with lambdas allows powerful object querying capabilities. I'm curious: what benefit do you gain by removing references to LINQ?

Comment: @jalf: As Jon Skeet already wrote, when targetting .NET 2.0, lambdas are available, but LINQ isn't. That's (in my opinion) the main reason.

Comment: @OregonGhost: It can be - see my edit :) (That's only LINQ to Objects, admittedly - but that's the most commonly used bit of LINQ IME.)

Comment: Instead of manually removing the references, it's better create the project to target 2.0 from start. There's a combo box somewhere in the New Project Dialog.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Lambdas can be used whenever you want. They're a new language feature. Linq uses them, but you don't have to use linq.

```
Action blah = () => { System.Console.WriteLine("Hello World!"); }
blah(); // will write Hello World! to the console
```

Answer (score 16):

Lambda expressions are completely independent of LINQ. Indeed, you can use them when targeting a .NET 2.0 project from VS2008 or VS2010. Likewise if you're using .NET 3.5, you can use expression trees without using LINQ - although that's less common in my experience.

However, I'd urge you not to avoid LINQ - it's a hugely powerful tool. I'm personally *slightly* wary of LINQ providers which need to do translations via `Queryable` - they're harder to predict - but LINQ to Objects is pure gold. What do you dislike about it? Note that you don't have to use query expressions in order to use LINQ - you can write queries in "dot notation" using lambda expressions:

```
var query = people.Where(p => p.Age >= 18)
                  .Select(p => p.Name);
```

... so if query expressions were putting you off, you don't need to worry about them.

EDIT: Just to counter a comment to the question itself - you *can* use LINQ to Objects with .NET 2.0, via the [LINQBridge](http://code.google.com/p/linqbridge) project.

Comment: How expensive is LINQ in terms of performance? Say i want to use only
for dictionary (container structures) queries.

Comment: Queries that chain a lot of methods can have some overhead because of the chained enumerators. But I wouldn't shy away from LINQ because of performance. If there is a hit (shown with profiling), I would change *the exact* query that causes the trouble.

Answer (score 4):

It's important to understand where lambda expressions come from and why they are used.  It's true that most people hear of lambdas through LINQ, but LINQ is simply implementing a feature that was introduced in version 3.0 of the C# language as a successor (I think) to anonymous methods.

Lambdas are actually used with `delegate`s and when you use a lambda, what you're actually doing is assigning a method to a `delegate`.  However, you can avoid using the `delegate` keyword because the compiler can infer that you are using a `delegate` simply because you are using a lambda expression.

Thus the following are the same thing:

```
MyDel del = delegate (int x) {return x + 1;} ; // Using an anonymous method
MyDel le1 = x => x + 1;                        // Using a lambda expression
```

Keep in mind that a delegate doesn't execute its methods until it is called.  Thus, even though you see `x => x + 1` in your lambda expression, this actually isn't executed until you call `le1(someInt)`.  You may have seen this in LINQ where the query isn't executed until the delegate is called.

In short (and I'm not know for my brevity), a lambda allows you to express a method call in shortform without having to declare it in the body of your class.

My source for this answer if from Daniel Solis' [Illustrated C# 2008](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590599543), pp.375-377.

Answer (score 3):

No, you can use lambdas just like anonymous methods, no LINQ is required.

Answer (score 2):

Lambdas can absolutely be used without linq, I do it all the time.  Here's a [code sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1782793/super-simple-example-for-a-delegate-event-in-c-net/1782908#1782908) I posted elsewhere that uses a lambda with no linq in sight.